# running package throws ImportError: No module named image

Tags: cx-freeze

Using `cx_freeze` under ubuntu 12.04. The generation of the package is
done without any errors but when I try to run the package as a
standalone, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts /Console.py",
    line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
     m m   File "Setup_cx_freeze.py", line 3, in <module>
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/__init__.py",
     line 4, in <module>
     from cx_Freeze.dist import *
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py",
     line 3, in <module>
     import distutils.command.install
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 21,   in          <module>
      from site import USER_BASE
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
      main()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 540, in main
      abs__file__()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 100, in abs__file__
     m.__file__ = os.path.abspath(m.__file__)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
      __import__(self.__name__)
      ImportError: No module named image
```

I think what to focus on is the last sentence. `"ImportError: No module named image."`

The application runs without any problems in pure python environment
So why do I get the Error when running it as a "freeze" package? The
fault is somehow introduced when generating the freeze-package.

Comment: I've just got this error myself.  Did you ever solve it?

Comment: did you ever fix this one?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up fixing this by explicitly including the package "email.mime" in the setup.py script build exe options.

Comment: Putting `email` into the `packages` list should also work. Since it's using dynamic imports, cx_Freeze doesn't automatically detect what modules are in use, so it needs to be explicitly told to copy them.

Comment: @ThomasK funny thing, I'm having the same problems and there is nothing in my software that uses the email lib. I added the email.mime to my packages and nothing could make it work though.

Answer (score 1):

Missing 'image' is just first part of the problem. Try to add this to your code:

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage
```

This resolved problems with 'image', 'audio' and 'message'.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this by installing Python Imaging Library: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

1) `python setup.py build`

2) `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about module "Image" not "image"??

Comment: No, I'm not sure. This was over a year ago and I haven't touched Python since.